# Internal Microphone Not Working Dell 5300

Tags: microphone, 23.10

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 on my Dell Latitude 5300 laptop, dual-booted with Windows. Currently, I am experiencing an issue with my internal microphone. While using Ubuntu, my laptop microphone cannot be used for speaking, but if I switch to Windows, the microphone functions normally. Has anyone encountered the same issue? How can I resolve this problem without reinstalling Ubuntu?
enter image description here
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
**OS**: Ubuntu 23.10 x86_64 
**Kernel**: 6.5.0-26-generic

```
Ports:
    analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8900, availability group: Legacy 1, availability unknown)
    analog-input-headphone-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
    analog-input-headset-mic: Headset Microphone (type: Headset, priority: 8800, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
Active Port: analog-input-internal-mic
Formats:
    pcm
```

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of *Settings -> Sound* window